# wordpress plugin inline google spreadsheet viewer, datatable_column_defs attribute not working

Tags: wordpress, datatables

Hi I am using inline google spreadsheet viewer to display datatable for my spreadsheet, I want to customise the datatable columns for which I am using attributes

> **datatables_colum**
>   and
>   **datatables_column_defs**

But none of above works it shows error **Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
Make sure that you have the correct URL and the file exists.**

Here is what I am using:

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ABCDEFG/edit#gid=123456" datatables_page_length="400" datatables_columns="[null,null,null,null,null,null,{'type':'num-fmt'},null,null,null,null]" query="select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M" ]
```

This is the manual way using **datatables_columns** attribute

and other is using **datatables_column_defs**:

```
[gdoc key="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ABCDEFG/edit#gid=123456" datatables_page_length="400" datatables_column_defs="[{'type':'num-fmt', 'targets':'G'}]" query="select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M" ]
```

When I remove these attributes the data is shown correctly.

I don't Know what I am doing wrong but its not working anyway. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks
**Note:** The above spreadsheet URLs are only for example mine is different and working.